# Существуют ли методы взаимодействия со статьями вк

Tags: python, строки, vkontakte-api, requests, вконтакте

У меня есть большое количество текстовой и графической информации, которую я хотел бы опубликовать в своей группе ВКонтакте в удобной для изучения форме. Создание статьи первым делом пришло на ум, однако, ВКонтакте не предоставляет возможность взаимодействия с ними.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какими средствами я могу реализовать создание и заполнение статьи в группе ВКонтакте? Я предпочел бы использовать язык программирования Python, так как я уже использую его для решения других задач. Кроме того, мне также важно соблюдать правила сообщества ВКонтакте.